# How to get the difference between two dates with php and symfony 4?

Tags: javascript, php, twig, symfony4, twig-extension

I am developing a holiday management project. There is an entity called `Conge` which includes `date_departure`, `date_retrun` and `period`. I made a form and the view. I would like to set the difference between the date of departure and the date of return. For example, if the user chooses dates from '04-05-2019' to '04-08-2019', how can I get and display the difference in days using javascript, php, and symfony4?

Comment: Difference in terms of? days? hours? mins? or..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always going to use the m-d-Y format for your dates you can use just PHP to give you the number of days difference.

```
$departure ="04-05-2019";
$arrival = "04-08-2019";
$departure = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $departure)->getTimestamp();
$arrival = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $arrival)->getTimestamp();
echo ($arrival - $departure) / (24*60*60);  // 86400 might save some math
```

Answer (score 1):

Use momentjs (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var departureRaw = $(".departure").val();
var departureDate = moment(departureRaw);

var returnRaw = $(".return").val();
var returnDate = moment(returnRaw);

var difference = departureDate.diff(returnDate, 'days');
```

Answer (score 1):

for php, as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/11335154) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) you can use ->diff() function. I don't think than Symfony have any function for that